# Form stuck in query mode after adding new fields

Tags: oracle, debugging, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have an old oracle form in 6i, recently i added two radio groups linked under two different fields. 
Whenever I go into query mode - F7 and enter my search criteria , it hangs while exiting the query mode - F8.
I tried getting the query through TOAD and ran it separately and it runs without any issues.

If i remove those fields, the query works properly.

Anything which I missed regarding those new fields or radio groups?  In fact, I compared those fields and radio group items with existing other fields and they are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a debug issue. It looks like you added fields that break a triggers that is called in your Form at some point (e.g. "<kbd>KEY-NXTBLK</kbd>", "<kbd>KEY-NEXT-ITEM</kbd>", ...).

Things you should do:

- learn how to use ***Forms Debugger*** (might be tricky, I myself forgot it sorry)
- if too tricky at your point, ***enable Forms tracing***, to know what happens when you do your action - this depends on the server where your form runs; Google is your friend.
- identify which triggers are raised when you do your action
- check on your database what query is run when you do you're action, e.g. most heavy queries of the day:

  ```
  SELECT sql_text, cpu_time, elapsed_time,  last_load_time FROM v$sql
   where to_date(last_load_time,'YYYY-MM-DD/HH24:MI:SS') > trunc(sysdate)
  order by cpu_time desc;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle Forms annoying feature - if you select from database other value then expected in `Radio Button Value Property`, Oracle forms discards whole selected record without any warning and fetches next record.

For example if you have radio buttons defined for M (male) and F (female) and in your database are records with X value in corresponding column, these records will never be displayed. If you have lots of these records, forms take long time to find first acceptable row, program looks like freezing.

There is simple solution - set `Mapping of Other Values property` to assign non expected value to valid Radio group state.

You can find the same behavior on checkbox and list items.